# How to download a file in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask  how to download my files in public directory with renamed files in laravel 6 ?
What should I do in `download()` method , and on the blade ?

I just want to download saved file as same as `id` (autoincreacement).

thankyou before.

here the `route/web.php`

```php
    Route::middleware('role:purchasing|admin')->group(function(){
        Route::resource('purchasing', Laporan\PurchasingController::class);
        Route::get('purchasing/delete/{id}', ['as' => 'purchasing.delete', 'uses' => 'PurchasingController@delete']);
        Route::get('purchasing/{id}/download', 'PurchasingController@download')->name('purchasing.download');
    });
```

here's my controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Laporan;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Purchasing;
use App\User;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class PurchasingController extends Controller
{
// .. another codes ..

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // ..using validate here ..

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $namaFile = time() . "_Purchasing_" . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = 'storage/laporan/purchasing';
        $file->move($path, $namaFile);

        $data = new Purchasing([
            'staff'     => Auth::user()->name,
            'divisi'    => Auth::user()->role,
            'tanggal'   => $request->get('tanggal'),
            'title'     => $request->get('title'),
            'desc'      => $request->get('desc'),
            'file'      => $namaFile,
            'status'    => $request->get('status')
        ]);
        $data->save();
        Alert::success('Sukses', 'Laporan berhasil ditambahkan!');
        return redirect('/purchasing');
    }

    public function download($id)
    {
        // what should i do here ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: file located on `$path = 'storage/laporan/purchasing';`

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the directory in the `$path` variable which is

> storage/laporan/purchasing

Inside this directory, you will find the file by the name from your variable `$namaFile`

In the download function, get the file name from the database and link it to the directory.

```
$purchasing_file = Purchasing::find($id)->namaFile;
$link_to_download = storage_path('laporan/purchasing').$purchasing_file;
```

Hope I answered your questions, thanks.

Comment: The file `"C:\xampp\htdocs\path\storage\laporan/purchasing/"` does not exist.